# Display UITableViewCell reordering control without shifting cell contents to the right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I implemented moveRowAtIndexPath to rearrange the order of the cells in a UITableView and set UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone so it displays only the reordering controls when in editing mode.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

}
```

It works fine but when entering in editing mode it still indents the contents of each cell to the right expecting to make room for a deletion or insertion control. I am not using either so it becomes an odd empty space. Is there a way to avoid this behavior in editing mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting shouldIndentWhileEditing to NO on your UITableViewCell?

Comment: Thanks much. Based on your answer I found the UITableViewDelegate method tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: which sets the option for all cells.

Answer (score 4):

Try This UITableViewDelegate Methods. It will allow reordering without showing the Delete button on left and without shift the row to right:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please check the official Apple Developer Document for the best understanding 


1. UITableViewDataSource Protocol:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/  

2. UITableViewDelegate Protocol:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/